# Marginal effects of logit in weighted survey data using R

Tags: r, survey, marginal-effects

I´m trying to estimate marginal effect of a logit model in which I have several dichotomous explanatory variables.

Let's say the model estimated by

```
logit<- svyglm ( if_member ~ if_female + dummy_agegroup_2 + dummy_agegroup_3 + dummy_education_2 + dummy_education_3 + dummy_education_4, family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"), design = survey_design)
```

I know about the **marginpred** function in survey package, but I am not very familiar with it. I have only dichotomous variebles in the model so I am wondering how to estimate marginal effects by this function, especially I am not sure about the ***predictat*** (A data frame giving values of the variables in model to predict at).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468360/how-can-i-generate-marginal-effects-for-a-logit-model-when-using-survey-weights

Comment: @Carl Yeah I saw this link before I had asked my question. However, there is not the answer on my question. I have tried to modify logitmfx function in accordance with the link you provided but without success.

Comment: not sure if it's of any value, but the predicted marginals section of this how-to might help?  http://www.asdfree.com/2015/11/statistically-significant-trends-with.html

Comment: This might be a better fit on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for marginal **effects** or marginal **predictions**?

As the name implies, the `marginpred()` function returns **predictions**. The argument for `predictat` is a data frame with both the control variables and the variables that are in the model. Let me emphasize that: control variables should be left out of the model.

```r
library("survey")

odds2prob <- function(x) x / (x + 1)
prob2odds <- function(x) x / (1 - x)
expit <- function(x) odds2prob(exp(x))
logit <- function(x) log(prob2odds(x))

set.seed(1)

survey_data <- data.frame(
  if_female = rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = 0.5), 
  agegroup = factor(sample(x = 1:3, size = 100, replace = TRUE)), 
  education = NA_integer_,
  if_member = NA_integer_)
survey_data["agegroup"] <- relevel(survey_data$agegroup, ref = 3)
# Different probabilities between female and male persons
survey_data[survey_data$if_female == 0, "education"] <- sample(
  x = 1:4, 
  size = sum(survey_data$if_female == 0), 
  replace = TRUE, 
  prob = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3))
survey_data[survey_data$if_female == 1, "education"] <-sample(
  x = 1:4, 
  size = sum(survey_data$if_female == 1), 
  replace = TRUE, 
  prob = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5))
survey_data["if_member"] <- rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = 
                                     expit((survey_data$education - 3)/2))
survey_data["education"] <- factor(survey_data$education)
survey_data["education"] <- relevel(survey_data$education, ref = 3)
survey_design <- svydesign(ids = ~ 1, data = survey_data)

logit <- svyglm(if_member ~ if_female + agegroup + education, 
                family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"), 
                design = survey_design)
exp(cbind(`odds ratio` = coef(logit), confint(logit)))
newdf <- data.frame(if_female = 0:1, education = c(3, 3), agegroup =  = c(3, 3))
# Fails
mp <- marginpred(model = logit, adjustfor = ~ agegroup + education, 
                 predictat = newdf, se = TRUE, type = "response")
logit2 <- svyglm(if_member ~ if_female, 
                family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"), 
                design = survey_design)
mp <- marginpred(model = logit2, adjustfor = ~ agegroup + education, 
                 predictat = newdf, se = TRUE, type = "response")
# Probability for male and for female persons controlling for agegroup and education
cbind(prob = mp, confint(mp))
```

That's how I estimate marginal **effects** with the `survey` package:

```r
# Probability difference between female and male persons
# when agegroup and education are set to 3
svycontrast(full_model, quote(
  (exp(`(Intercept)` + if_female) / (exp(`(Intercept)` + if_female) + 1)) - 
  (exp(`(Intercept)`) / (exp(`(Intercept)`) + 1))))
# Can't use custom functions like expit :_(
```

There are probably smarter ways, but I hope it helps.

Please note that the difference between the probabilities predicted by `marginpred()` is different from the difference estimated by `svycontrast()`. The probabilities predicted by `marginpred()` don't seem to be affected by changing the value of the control variables (in example, 
`education = c(4, 4)` instead of `education = c(3, 3)`), but the estimates from `svycontrast()` are affected as implied by the regression model.